# How i can get Data using Angularjs Resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, kendo-ui

I am trying to pre-populated data from backend using rest service passing id to retrieve data,this is edit mode when user click on edit process all input fields should be pre-populate associated with that id.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
    ng-readonly="readOnly" ng-model="process.Name"
    placeholder="Process Name" ng-maxlength="50" name="processName"
    ng-required="true" data-required-msg="Process Name">
```

CONTROLLES.JS

```
$scope.editMode = false;
if ($scope.process_id != '_new' && $scope.process_id > 0) {
    var process = Process.get({},{'Id': 2551});
    console.log("get method")
    $scope.editMode = true;
}
```

SERVICE.JS

```
App.factory('Process', function($resource) {
    return $resource('app/prcs/rest/process/:id', {}, {
        'query' : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true
        },
        'get' : {
            method : 'GET'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var process = Process.get({},{'Id': 2551});
```

you need something like this:

```
$scope.process = Process.get({},{'Id': 2551});
```

You cannot reach Controller's variables from View. You can only access those defined in $scope. Also don't forget to inject $scope into your controller.

Comment: $scope.process helped but now i am getting an error in response body . {"timestamp":1421359230598,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException","message":"Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: [\"lookupCode\"])","path":"/app/prcs/rest/process"}

Comment: It seems that now you have issue with your backend side, you can check if you get the same error when you point your browser directly to app/prcs/rest/process/2551 page, maybe you get more info there, but otherwise I don't have much experience with Spring and JVM, but you can probably start a new question for that.

Comment: I appreciate your response let me drill down this error little more to see what is  exactly creating this error. Thanks